# document.createElement is not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a table structure

```
<table id ="tbl1" >
            <thead>

              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
<button class="btn-danger btn fileinput-button" type="button">-</button></td>
              </tr>
        </thead>
          </table>
```

I have to build dynamic rows in javascript...I am using the below code to generate..

```
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML = filename;


            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element2 = document.createElement("button");
            element2.type = "button";
            element2.className = "btn-danger btn fileinput-button";
            var element3 = document.createElement("span");
            element3.innerHTML = "-";
            element2.appendChild(element3);
            cell2.appendChild(element2);
```

The above code works fine in Fire fox but in ie button td is not creating. Could any one help on this.

Many Thanks
Anna

Comment: works fine for me in IE7,9 btw why aren't you using jQuery to do this? as ur question has a jQuery tag!

Comment: what version of IE are you using?

Comment: What errors do you get?, did you try debugging it in developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to this in jQuery:

```
    var filename = 'sdsd';
    var $btn = $('<button type="button">-</button>');
    $btn.attr('class', 'btn-danger btn fileinput-button');

    var $tr = $('<tr />');
    $tr.append('<td>'+filename+'</td>');
    $tr.append('<td />');
    $tr.find('td:last').append( $btn );
    $('#tbl1').append( $tr );
```

the error is coz of this line in ur code:
`element2.type = "button";`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sally,

I have changed my code like below, this is also working.

```
var strTableRow = "<tr><td>" + filename + "</td><td><button class='btn-danger btn fileinput-button' type='button'>-</button></td></tr>";

$('#'+tableID).append(strTableRow);
```

Many Thanks
Anna